# Creating parallax effect using useEffect to manipulate DOM

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks

Currently I'm trying to create a parallax effect in React where my image and text are in a fixed position vertically, but move from side to side horizontally.

Reference Image:

[image]

I have managed to configure the first 2 slides using z-index for each element and an eventListener for scroll. But for my third slide, I want the image to start moving towards the right which currently is endlessly scrolling to the left, and my text that has the lowest z-index to the left which is getting covered by a higher z-index element. How can I fix this to get the output of my third slide.

CodeSandBox(view in fullscreen to get better idea): https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-rumple-s8cr6?file=/src/App.js

Code:

```
const [index, setIndex] = useState(false);
const [display, setDisplay] = useState(false);
useEffect(function onFirstMount() {
    const changeBackground = () => {
      let value = window.scrollY;
      let img = document.getElementById("moveLeft");
      let text = document.getElementById("moveUp");
      let text2 = document.getElementById("text2");
      let text3 = document.getElementById("text3");

      img.style.transform = `translateX(-${value * 0.25}px)`;
      text.style.marginTop = "-" + value * 0.5 + "px";
      text2.style.transform = `translateX(${value * 1.3}px)`;
      text3.style.transform = `translateX(-${value * 1.3}px)`;
if (value > 600){
        setIndex(true);
      } else{
        setIndex(false)
      }
    };
    window.addEventListener("scroll", changeBackground);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", changeBackground);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="App">
        <div className="middletext" id="moveUp" style={{ zIndex: "9" }}>
          Random Text
        </div>

        <div class="inflow">
          <div class="positioner">
            <div class="fixed" style={{ zIndex: "10" }}>
              <div id="moveLeft">
                <img
                  alt="passport"
                  src="https://cdn.britannica.com/87/122087-050-1C269E8D/Cover-passport.jpg"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="halfWindow" style={{ zIndex: "8" }}></div>
          <div>
            <div class="fixedText">
              <div id="text2" className="text2" style={{ zIndex: "7" }}>
                Random Text
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="secondhalfWindow" style={{ zIndex: "6" }}></div>
          <div>
            <div class="secondfixedText" style={{ zIndex: index?"11":"5" }}>
              <div id="text3" className="text3">
                Random Text 2
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="App"></div>
```